# Allow only image edits in WordPress TinyMCE editor

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I have a typical use case in my current project. I want my client to be able to edit only pictures in the WordPress site I am building for them. They should not be able to edit any text whatsoever, anywhere on the site.

I thought of two different paths to take - 1. Use jQuery to edit the images from the front end, but I don't know how I will save the changes to database given that the entire post content is in one place on the WordPress DB.
2. Disable text editing in the TinyMCE for that particular role, so the user can only open up posts in the TinyMCE and can change only the images using the Add Media button.

Which path would you take among these two? And if there is another better solution, please guide me to it.